# How to force a group of table columns to have the same width using CSS only?

Tags: html, css

Please consider the following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sasoRP/uLm2n9oo/

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name"></div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Yes</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">No</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name">Market Name 1</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I want that the last 2 or 3 columns (class: .column-selection) to always have the same width.
I also want that width to just fit to the content of the largest column.

Looking at the fiddle, the behavior of "Table 1" and "Table 7" are perfect for me! But the problems of this solution are:

- Table 2 is pretty bad. I wanted the "Yes No" columns width to fit
  their content as in table 1, leaving the remaining space for the
  market name column.
- Table 3 is not ok, because I want the "Half Time" and "Second Half"
  to be the same width.
- Table 4 is not ok, because I want "same width" and "fit to content".
- Tables 4, 5 and 6 are not ok, because I want "same width" and "fit to
  content".

I'm a bit lost for a solution to this **without applying JS magic**.

Do you know of any **pure CSS** solution for these requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Use `table-layout:fixed` on `.table`, then assign `width:33%` to each of the top table-cells. I added `.header` classes to each top cell to illustrate. I also added `border-collapse:collapse` for a better fit, but it's not totally necessary.

The `table-layout:fixed` property will make a table behave in a more intuitive manner. If you set a column width, it stays at that width. It basically allows you to set widths of each column and the table's width without the content influencing it. Total control plus the browser will render it faster as well. I set the first table's column widths to 33% making them equal. As you can see, the other tables followed suit without any explicit widths because initially a fixed table will evenly divide the width of the table equally among themselves.

It's confusing when you say "same width" and "fit to content" because at times one cannot exist with the other, so I left the others as "equal widths". "same width" and "fit to content" if it were possible for table CSS (I don't think it's actually possible w/o JS*), could stretch one column to 80% and forcing the other columns to conform to stretch at equal lengths would mean that the table itself would have to increase by 140%.
See this [article](https://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/) for more details.

#### EDIT

*Upon further consideration, I believe the exact behavior can be achieved with flexbox. That would be beyond the scope of simple tables...

[<kbd>FIDDLE</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/jq8fmycn/1/)

#### SNIPPET

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.table-container {
  width: 638px;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
  position: relative;
}
.column {
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.column.column-selection {} .column.column-market-name {
  text-align: left;
}
.header1 {
  width: 10%;
}
.header2 {
  width: 20%;
}
.header3 {
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Table 1
</h1>

<div class="table-container">
  <div class="table table-1">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name header3"></div>
      <div class="column column-selection header3">Yes</div>
      <div class="column column-selection heade3">No</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name">Market Name 1</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name">Very Long Market Name 2 fasdf sfsa fdsafasdfadsf s adsfadsf sadfsadfasfd adsfadsfsa dfadfasd fdsafadsfasd</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name">Market Name 3</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>
  Table 2
</h1>

<div class="table-container">
  <div class="table table-2">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name"></div>
      <div class="column column-selection header1">Yes</div>
      <div class="column column-selection header1">No</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name">Market Name 1</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name">Market Name 2</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name">Market Name 3</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>
  Table 3
</h1>

<div class="table-container">
  <div class="table table-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name"></div>
      <div class="column column-selection header2">Half Time</div>
      <div class="column column-selection header2">Second Half Result</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name">Market Name 1</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name">Very Long Market Name fasdf sfsa fdsafasdfadsf dasdsad asdasd asdasd asdad safsf asdfafgsfddsadf adsfasdf sadfasd fdsafadsfasd</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name">Market Name 3</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>
  Table 4
</h1>

<div class="table-container">
  <div class="table table-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name"></div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Half Time</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Second Half Result</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name">Market Name 1</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name">Market Name 2</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name">Market Name 3</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>
  Table 5
</h1>

<div class="table-container">
  <div class="table table-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name"></div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Borussia Munchenglabach</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">The Draw</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Wolverhampton Wanderes</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name">Market Name 1</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name">Very Long Market Name fasdf adsafd adfds fsadfsa dfsadfsad fsadfsadf safdasdfsfsa fdsafasdfadsf sadfasd fdsafadsfasd</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name">Market Name 3</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>
  Table 6
</h1>

<div class="table-container">
  <div class="table table-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name"></div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Borussia Munchenglabach</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">The Draw</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Wolverhampton Wanderes</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name">Market Name 1</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name">Market Name 2</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name">Market Name 3</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<h1>
  Table 7
</h1>

<div class="table-container">
  <div class="table table-7">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name"></div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Home or Draw</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Home or Away</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Draw or Away</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name">Market Name 1</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name">Very Long Market Name fasdf adsafd adfds fsadfsa dfsadfsad fsadfsadf safdasdfsfsa fdsafasdfadsf sadfasd fdsafadsfasd</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name">Market Name 3</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>
  Table 8
</h1>

<div class="table-container">
  <div class="table table-8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name"></div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Home or Draw</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Home or Away</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Draw or Away</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name">Market Name 1</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name">Market Name 2</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column column-market-name">Market Name 3</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
      <div class="column column-selection">Cel</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: zer00ne, this solution just forces all columns to have the same width. I want to force the same width only on the "column-selection" columns (last 2 or 3, depending on the table in the fiddle). The remaining space should be used by the first column (".column-market-name"). I also want the width of these "column-selection" to fit to the content of the largest one (as it happens for tables 1 and 7).

Comment: Yeah I was still editing. I made 3 classes: `.header1, 2, & 3` at 10% 20% and 33%. See how they work as you described? Also read my babbling about "same width" and "fit content".

Comment: Yes, I'm reading it now. I think you're right when you say that "same width" and "fit to content" might not be possible with CSS only. That's why I've posted this question here. Maybe someone could have a solution for this. I think that flex (as you have referecend) might help on this. I'll give it a try and then I'll keep you updated. Thanks for your great effort on this zer00ne. I really appreciate :)

Comment: Not a problem, sir. If I happen to figure a way with flex, I'll post it here, happy coding.:)